# A basic question on $L_p$ norm

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

How to prove that if $\mu(\omega) < \infty$ then $L_p$ norm increases to $L_\infty$ norm ?

Comment: I think you mean $ L^p $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $\|f\|_p \le \|f\|_\infty \mu(\omega)^{1/p}$.
2. Given $\epsilon>0$, there is a set of positive measure $A$ on which $|f| \ge  \|f\|_\infty - \epsilon$.  Hence $\|f\|_p \ge (\|f\|_\infty - \epsilon)\mu(A)^{1/p}$.

Comment: How to prove that $L^p$ norm is increasing with $p$ ?

Comment: @aaaaaa It is only necessarily true if $\mu(\omega) \le 1$.  Then it follows by Holder's inequality.  If $\mu(\omega) > 1$, then the example $f \equiv 1$ shows it is not necessarily increasing.